# How to locate a point into a bounding box or polygon in osmosis?

Tags: android, geolocation, osmosis

I try to locate if a point, with its latitude and longitude coordinates, is into a city which coordinates are in a geom object or in a bounding box in Osmosis.
I do this because I want to download a piece map in my Android application that correspond with the city in which the point is. 
Is there any way in Osmosis to do this? Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can convert to Z/X/Y format of the given lat/long and then load the particular tile which this lat/long corresponds too. Hope this should help. I've used osmdroid, for this purpose and i'm able to load either online/offline.